# How to store order of items in case we have a bitmask that contains a list of items?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a bitmask in my db for storing a list of items. Before now I just rendered these items one by one on the screen. But now user should have an ability to set the order of items. I have a solution that I dislike: to store ids list in the field using some separator (something like this 1|8|4|16).

Can anyone help me to find another solution?

Comment: So you're wanting to get rid of your bitmask solution in place of something else that can handle order?

Comment: How many items are there? Is the number fixed?

Comment: No, I want to have a bitmask to store a list. But bitmask can't be used to determine the order of items. So I want to find a way to store the order of items, but to keep my bitmask alive.

Comment: There are 15 items. But it can be more in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of items is capped at a certain number (say, 15) you could store a list of small numbers in a larger numeric type. Essentially, your list becomes a "mask" of 4-bit groups, where each group represents a number from 0 to 15, inclusive. With 15 items you need 60 bits to store such a list. Conveniently, most databases support 64-bit integer types, so all you need to do is implementing a packing algorithm. Since the number of items is 15 and the number of states that can be stored in 4 bits is 16, you can use combination of all zeros to mean "not present"; all non-zero combinations represent a number of the item.

This is a lot faster and significantly more compact than storing lists of numbers in a string. It is harder to expand, though, because the length of the bit group (4 in this case) depends on the number of items that you desire to store.